# How do I take time away from a time in datetime?

Tags: python-3.7

I am working on a project that can take on time away from another time and tell me the waiting time. Eg:

10:43:56 - 10:39:46 = 4 minutes 10 seconds.

I've tried to use multiple libraries which of none have worked. After that I resorted to online tutorials with datetime as it seemed to be the closest one to what I am looking for.

```py
import datetime

a = "9:54:34"
b = "9:52:34"
print(datetime.timedelta(a, b))
```

I was looking to see if there is a function along the lines of datetime.timedeltasubtract(a, b) but thats not a thing. Help would be appreciated, please ignore my lack of skill..

I was expecting the output to be 00:02:00 or 2 or 2 minutes. But the error was

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/photo/Desktop/CJ
>   work project/main.py", line 7, in 
>       print(datetime.timedelta(a, b)) TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta seconds component: str

Answer (score 0):

As first step is necessary to convert the strings to `datetime` objects using `datetime.strptime` function ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)). Then you can subtract these two times:

```
import datetime

a = "9:54:34"
b = "9:52:34"

d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(a,'%H:%M:%S')
d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(b,'%H:%M:%S')

print(d1 - d2)
```

Prints:

```
0:02:00
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. Is there anyway I could pull time from a string? Eg:  09:31:12 3370159 09:31:12 TimeStamp
How would I pull one of the time values?

Comment: @NoCopywriteSpectrums You could split the string `09:31:12 3370159 09:31:12 ` and call `strptime()` on each part with appropriate formatting string.

Comment: How would I strip the time. Like I said. Sorry for the noobishness.

Comment: Ah sorry. Anyhow, problem 2 lol . 
I have this data:
7A2K0007  09:33:35   Photograph 
How would I just grab the time. Because all of this data is in an array and splitting it is not possible.

Comment: Sorry it didn't show but there're commas in between the value.

`7A2K0007,,09:33:35,,,Photograph

Comment: @NoCopywriteSpectrums You could use: `"7A2K0007,,09:33:35,,,Photograph".replace(","," ").split()[1]`